# Cross reference to specific paragraph styles in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, cross-reference

In order to make a cross reference, I have to choose from some predefined element types, such as Heading, Figure, Table.

Is it possible to make cross references to specific paragraph styles?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to make a Table Of Contents (TOC) that contains any selected part of
the document, but it requires specially marking each text that is to be included.
This is done as follows.

Select the text you want in the TOC and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>.

This will open the dialog with the selected text :

[image: image1]

You may select here in which TOC the entry will appear in (more than one are possible),
and the level of the entry.

To insert the TOC from the References tab, click the button "Table of Contents",
and choose "Custom Table of Contents...". In the dialog, click Options, then
uncheck "Styles" and "Outline levels" and check "Table entry fields":

[image: image2]

For an advanced technique that allows the use of StyleRef fields to
customize the format of the entries in the TOC, see the article
[Useful StyleRef tricks](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/StyleRef.htm).